# Trust level of local domains on public UCC 

Tags: rds, windows-terminal-services, ucc

Are local domain names trusted on a public UCC (Unified Communications Certificate)?

I want to use it for my 2008R2 RD Gateway and RD Web environment. The certificate should also be trusted when logging in from outside the .local domain.

Answer (score 1):

A UCC from a public "well known" Certificate Authority will have their root certificate trusted by most devices.

Now like any certificate, a UCC will only work well if used for host's that are in it's list.  If you want to use a single UCC for www.domain.com, mail.domain.com, and something like mail.domain.local then they all have to be in the certificate request. You need to check with the UCC provider as to if they will allow .local to be added to the list.